# Install multiple packages on linux (like pip install -r requirements.txt)

Tags: linux, pip, apt-get

As the title is pretty clear (I hope so :) ), I'm looking for an easy way to install many softwares through apt-get command, I have created a shell script where I put all software I need but it's not very clean to do that I assume. The cleanest way is to tell apt-get to read into a file like the command pip.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the list of packages in a text file(say `test.txt`) with package names separated by spaces, like this -

```
python ruby foo bar
```

then you can just install with `apt-get` like this -

```
sudo apt-get install $(cat test.txt)
```